# Guide me how to change file association with single click in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, file-association

I have used this site for years for finding answers. This is my first question today..lol

I have a Dell 2-in-1 laptop with touchscreen with windows 8.1 (64 bit) installed.

So i use it in two ways. (1) traditional laptop (using keyboard) (2) as tablet (using touchscreen)

I will be speicific here.

For example when using keyboard i would like to view images with picasa image viewer.
When using touchscreen i would like to use the default images app of windows 8.1

I know how to change file associations in windows

1. right click and open with
2. control panel > default programs

etc. etc.

but it all takes few clicks or keypresses.

The problem multiplies when i want to change association of more than one file type.. (e.g. not only .jpg but .png .gif etc......same way i want to use different video player for different modes)

So can we make any command line batch file / regedit script that automates this process at single click. or are there any other ideas about this.

Suggestions are welcome. sorry for the long explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to Use the Assoc Command](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/184082):

> To display a list of file extensions and their associations, type assoc at a command prompt, and then press ENTER.
>
> To display the association for a specific file extension, type assoc .<­xxx> at a command prompt, and then press ENTER, where <­xxx> is the file extension whose association you want to view.
>
> **To change the association for a specific file extension, type assoc .<­xxx>=<­file type> at a command prompt, and then press ENTER, where <­xxx> is the file extension whose association you want to change, and <­file type> is the program, dynamic data exchange (DDE), or OLE object you want to associate with the file extension.**
>
> To delete the association for a specific file extension, type assoc .<­xxx>= at a command prompt, and  then press ENTER, where <­xxx> is the file extension you want to delete.

The bold part is what you care about.

To set .jpg as picasa, use:

```
assoc.jpg=C:\Path\To\Picasa
```

in a command prompt or batch file. Remember that it must be ran with UAC admin, or on an admin account if windows XP.